# How to Implement routing based tab navigation swipe using angular js routing?

Tags: tabs, navigation, angular-ui-router, material-design, angular-material

What I hope to do is to implement a swipable navigation based on the Angular-UI--ROUTING and Angular-Material libraries. What I want to accomplish is to be able to swipe on the tabs, if the user wants to change to another one. So if a user swiped where it says "Tab #2" they would be able to move to TAB3 without having to actually click TAB3.

Below is a sample picture of the tabbed navigation that I have created so far:

[image: Angular Routing Material Tabs]

and below is a code snippet or at the [codepen](http://codepen.io/dstnation/pen/yyvjvP/)

```js
(function(angular, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('dsntApp', ['ngMaterial', "ui.router"])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');
        $stateProvider
        .state('view1', {
            url: "/view1",
            templateUrl: "partials/view1.html"
        })
        .state('view2', {
            url: "/view2",
            templateUrl: "partials/view2.html"
        })
        .state('view3', {
            url: "/view3",
            templateUrl: "partials/view3.html"
        })
        ;
    })
    .controller('tabCtrl', function($scope, $location, $log) {
        $scope.selectedIndex = 0;

        $scope.$watch('selectedIndex', function(current, old) {
            switch (current) {
                case 0:
                    $location.url("/view1");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $location.url("/view2");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $location.url("/view3");
                    break;
            }
        });
    });

})(angular);
```

```css
.intro {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size : 12px;
}

.demo {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.demo #content {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-animate.js"></script>
<div class="intro">
  This demonstration shows how Angular-Material Tabs can be used with Angular-UI-Router
<div>
  
<div ng-app="dsntApp" 
     ng-controller="tabCtrl"
     layout="column" class="demo" >

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/view1.html">  Tab #1 </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/view2.html">  Tab #2 </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/view3.html">  Tab #3 </script>
  <md-toolbar>
    <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <span>Toolbar</span>
    </h2>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs 
           md-selected="selectedIndex">
     <md-tab label="tab1"></md-tab> 
     <md-tab label="tab2"></md-tab>
     <md-tab label="tab3"></md-tab>  
  </md-tabs>

  <div id="content" ui-view flex> </div>

</div>
```

Comment: what you want from use..Its ionic framework..

Comment: Less pictures and broken links, more explanation & code. And plunker would be nice.

Comment: i want change  the tab view on swipe

Comment: @Pavan that is not the purpose of tabs. they don't lend mechanics of a swipable nature. its like supposed to be like tabs of a folder and the folder opens. swiping should move them left/right if there are too many, do you mean you want to change the tab if you swipe left/right on the body of the tab?

Comment: yes, i want to move the tab as well as the tab view should be scroll once it changed

Comment: @Pavan do you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the directives for that:

md-swipe-left:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.swipe/directive/mdSwipeLeft

md-swipe-right: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.swipe/directive/mdSwipeRight

```js
(function(angular, undefined) {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('dsntApp', ['ngMaterial', "ui.router"])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');
        $stateProvider
        .state('view1', {
            url: "/view1",
            templateUrl: "partials/view1.html"
        })
        .state('view2', {
            url: "/view2",
            templateUrl: "partials/view2.html"
        })
        .state('view3', {
            url: "/view3",
            templateUrl: "partials/view3.html"
        })
        ;
    })
    .controller('tabCtrl', function($scope, $location, $log) {
        $scope.selectedIndex = 0;

        $scope.onSwipeRight = function (){
      
       if ($scope.selectedIndex < 2){
        $scope.selectedIndex  = $scope.selectedIndex + 1;
    }
    // if you want to make all the tour
    else{
     $scope.selectedIndex  = 0;
    }
   }

   $scope.onSwipeLeft = function () {
      
        if ($scope.selectedIndex > 0){
     $scope.selectedIndex  = $scope.selectedIndex - 1;
     }
     // if you want to make all the tour
    else {
     $scope.selectedIndex  = 2;
    }
   }

        $scope.$watch('selectedIndex', function(current, old) {
            switch (current) {
                case 0:
                    $location.url("/view1");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $location.url("/view2");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $location.url("/view3");
                    break;
            }
        });
    });

})(angular);
```

```css
.intro {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size : 12px;
}

.demo {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.demo #content {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.13/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular-animate.js"></script>
<div class="intro">
  This demonstration shows how Angular-Material Tabs can be used with Angular-UI-Router
<div>
  
<div ng-app="dsntApp" 
     ng-controller="tabCtrl"
     layout="column" class="demo" >

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/view1.html">  Tab #1 </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/view2.html">  Tab #2 </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="partials/view3.html">  Tab #3 </script>
  <md-toolbar>
    <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <span>Toolbar</span>
    </h2>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs 
           md-selected="selectedIndex">
     <md-tab label="tab1"></md-tab> 
     <md-tab label="tab2"></md-tab>
     <md-tab label="tab3"></md-tab>  
  </md-tabs>

  <div id="content" ui-view flex md-swipe-left="onSwipeLeft()" md-swipe-right="onSwipeRight()"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great... but it doesn't animate whilst the user is swiping. It all happens in series: after the swipe completes, the page moves. That doesn't mimic the platform's behaviour and there are no visual cues to suggest that swiping is possible. It would be far preferable for the old tab to slide out, and the new one to slide in, whilst the user is dragging. That is what I'm trying to implement - any ideas?

Comment: @HughHughTeotl  I want to do the same thing, did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @AdamDiment not in any satisfactory way. It sounds like it should be a simple thing but it's weirdly very, very difficult. We ended up putting all the content in an Ionic ion-slide-box, which worked for our very specific case because there wasn't much content. But, as I say, it's a completely unsatisfactory solution for lots of reasons. Still seeking a good way of doing it. Please post any hints here if you find them! :)